# Add a Session Variable or Custom field to the Elmah Error Log table

Tags: asp.net, field, elmah

I want to add my own session variable to elmah error log table and display it. I already have modified the source code and added the new fields to Error.cs and other fields but I don't know but when I assign an HttpContext.Current.Session["MyVar"].tostring() value to my field in the constructor it stops logging exceptions and does not log any exception.

I just need to get the value of the session variable is there other way for this ? I read a post which he added fields for the email but it does not say where exactly should I get the session value. I also read that Session and Cookies ar e logged by default by Elmah but I dont know how to access them..Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your source code I can only make assumptions, but I think Elmah stops logging because you get an exception. This might happen because the `Session` property is null. The session is only available after the `PostAcquireRequestState` event and therefore you cannot count on this property to be always available.

I tried this myself and wrote a method like this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> CopySession(HttpSessionState session)
{
    if (session == null || session.Count == 0)
        return null;

    Dictionary<string, object> copy = new Dictionary<string, object>(session.Count);
    foreach (var key in session.Keys)
    {
        string name = key.ToString();
        copy.Add(name, session[name]);
    }

    return copy;
}
```

I call this method in the constructor of the Error class like this:

```
// _session is a new field that I added like this:
// private Dictionary<string, object> _session;
_session = CopySession(context.Session);
```

(just after server variables and the other context stuff gets copied. You will probably need to change the `IClonable` implementation to copy the `_session` field, too.)

In my tests this works as expected. I only checked in the `SqlErrorLog` class, but this will be the same for all the other *ErrorLog* classes: The error object contained all my session variables and I could store them in the database in whatever way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but this was [asked before and apparently there is a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973679/how-to-get-elmah-to-include-session-values), you might want to try that.